# Sphinx not generating documentation for declared module

Tags: python, python-sphinx

I followed [this tutorial](https://codeandchaos.wordpress.com/2012/07/30/sphinx-autodoc-tutorial-for-dummies/) directly.

My code lives in `N:/Tools/data/generic_accessor.py`.

And `generic_accessor.py` contains stuff like:

```
def access_hfri_returns(terms=[]):
    """
    This accesses HFRI returns data.
    Returns:

    """
```

In generic_accessor there are only functions and no classes.

I added:

```
sys.path.insert(0,"N:\\Tools\\data")
```

to `N:\Tools\data\conf.py`.

My `N:\Tools\data\index.rst` reads:

```
.. data documentation master file, created by
   sphinx-quickstart on Fri Feb 24 11:52:57 2017.
   You can adapt this file completely to your liking, but it should at least
   contain the root `toctree` directive.

Welcome to data's documentation!
================================

Contents:

.. toctree::
   :maxdepth: 2

.. automodule:: generic_accessor

Indices and tables
==================

* :ref:`genindex`
* :ref:`modindex`
* :ref:`search
```

I reran `make html` yet my `N:\Tools\data\_build\html\index.html` looks like this:
[image]

I do not see documentation for `generic_accessor` anywhere.

Thank you for any guidance.

Comment: Did you add `"sphinx.ext.autodoc"` to the `extensions` list in `conf.py`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the adaptations in the following. Note that I'm using .txt files.

index.txt

```
  .. data documentation master file, created by
   sphinx-quickstart on ...
   You can adapt this file completely to your liking, but it should at least
   contain the root `toctree` directive.

Welcome to data's documentation!
===================================

Contents:

.. toctree::
   :maxdepth: 2

   generic_accessor




Indices and tables
==================

* :ref:`genindex`
* :ref:`modindex`
* :ref:`search`
```

generic_accessor.txt

```
:mod:`generic_accessor`
==========================

.. automodule:: generic_accessor
    :members:
    :undoc-members:
    :inherited-members:
    :show-inheritance:
```

Comment: I also needed to explicitly add the parent directory in my config using `sys.path.insert(0,"N:\\tools")`